# Swift 2.0: Best Practice for communication to a REST API with JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest, nsurl

I started to migrated to Swift and just realised that most of the Sample Code does not work anymore in Swift 2.0, and it's really hard to get into as a beginner.

So what is the best practice to communicate with a REST API in Swift 2.0 with Swift methods from the standard libs?

Can anyone provide Swift 2.0 Code for the following scenario?

1. GET JSON Data from Service
2. Parse JSON (so its usable in Swift)
3. Send POST Request with JSON encoded Data

Please provide a solution without Frameworks. Hopefully it helps all other people trying to get Tutorials from the Web to work on Swift 2.0.

Comment: I'd suggest you attempt a good faith effort in converting one of the Swift 1.2 examples that you've found to Swift 2.0. The conversion really isn't very hard. See WWDC 2015 video [What's New in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=106) if you have questions about the Swift 2.0 syntax. In answer to your question, though, I'd suggest you consider the [Swift 2.0 branch of Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/swift-2.0), which simplifies the prepare of requests and the parsing of the responses.

Comment: @Rob according to all comments on Stackoverflow i decided to as specific for a Swift 2.0 BP - because JSON Parsing some function Parameters changed and as said, hard to get as a beginner. 2015 WWDC Videos do not really help with Step 2.

Answer (score 4):

I am a beginner too and I cannot say that what I do is best practice, but here is how I handled a GET request using **NSURLSession and closures**.

First, I defined a **NetworkOperation** class, which will handle the NSURLSession. It has the following attributes:

```
lazy var config: NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
lazy var session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: self.config)
let queryURL: NSURL
```

In the initializer I set the queryURL. The config and session vars are `lazy`because I want them to be initialized only when my network operation is used.

I then have a method which performs a GET request and retrieves JSON. This method accepts a closure as parameters. This closure will be provided by the caller, and allows me to capture my dataTask response into the calling context.

```
func downloadJSONFromURl(completion: ([String:AnyObject]?) -> ()) {
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: queryURL)

    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (let data: NSData?, let response: NSURLResponse?, let error: NSError?) -> Void in

        // 1: Check HTTP Response for successful GET request
        guard let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse, receivedData = data
        else {
            print("error: not a valid http response")
            return
        }

        switch (httpResponse.statusCode) {
        case 200:
            // 2: Create JSON object with data
            do {
                let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
                    as? [String:AnyObject]

                // 3: Pass the json back to the completion handler
                completion(jsonDictionary)
            } catch {
                print("error parsing json data")
            }
        default:
            print("GET request got response \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

This exemple is very simple and does not handle errors, but you can see how I parse JSON into a `[String:AnyObject]` into a try catch block.

Afterwards, I send back the dictionary into the closure named `completion`, which will perform the necessary validation on the JSON and then transform it into a Swift object.

In that closure, I use optional binding to safely build my object.
For instance, say I'm retrieving a book, and the JSON looks like this : 
`{title: "Some book", author:"J. Doe"}`

```
if let title = json["author"] as? String, author = json["author"] as? String {
    let book = Book(title: title, author: author)
    serviceCompletion(book)
}
```

Because I like closures, I then send the converted JSON into an other closure, provided to the service. You can see the full example on my [github](https://github.com/AdrianFraisse/SwiftSamples-Stormy). It's from a Treehouse tutorial.

I hope this helps a little.